# Change address layout in Invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

Can anybody tell me where I can change the layout and order of the addresses in the invoice pdf. I want to combine the City name with postcode number. Now the postcode number is combined with the county, which is not right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pdf address format can be modified from `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Templates->Pdf`

By default it looks like this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},|{{/if}}
{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}&lt;br/&gt;F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}&lt;br/&gt;VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
```

Just move the `{{postcode}}` where you need it.
It could be something like this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}&lt;br/&gt;F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}&lt;br/&gt;VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thnx!